# Can Azure free tier app service connect exeternal APIs?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, free, externalinterface

I have created an app service and hosted an API. I would like to connect with external API like push notification and payment gateways. Will the free tier supports to connect external APIs from Azure free tier plan

I tried to connect with IMDB apis, but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the actions are triggered by requests to the api that shouldn't be an issue. There's no limitation on outgoing messages compared to other tiers.

This would only be an issue if you would be running a background task or something similar, because the free (and shared) tier can't be always active. They only start up for requests and unload again when there's no traffic.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge let me check the implemented logic behind